# How to properly use jQuery to load JSON from a URL

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I'm a newbie learning JavaScript (specifically Leaflet.js for making maps), and I've run into a problem when trying to load data stored as JSON from a file on my Weebly site. The code I've used is:

```
    var test = "http://www.kingcountydata.weebly.com/files/theme/hrabasetopo.json?jsoncallback=?";
    $.getJSON(test, function (json) {
        console.log(json);
        console.log("success");
    });
```

This seems like it should work, but neither the JSON data nor "success" show up in my browser console.  Am I missing something obvious here?  Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You are trying to use jsonp in a site which does not looks like supporting it

Comment: also it does not looks like it is supporting CORS

Comment: also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Comment: only try with "http://www.kingcountydata.weebly.com/files/theme/hrabasetopo.json"

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using $.ajax() function like following and also debug the error:

```
  $.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://www.kingcountydata.weebly.com/files/theme/hrabasetopo.json?jsoncallback=?",
    success: function (dataCheck) {
                    console.log(dataCheck); 
                },
    error: function(data, errorThrown)
          {
              alert('request failed :'+errorThrown);
          }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks kapildilse! I tried this code and I get a "parse error". Any ideas for why this would be? Does it work for you?

Comment: Try by adding attribute: contentType: 'application/json' in ajax request as edited above.